# How do I use LIKE in a postgresql function for loop query

Tags: postgresql

having a view named jap.lots_name_view with products names as name

```
                       name
```

---

```
Flame 19#Pouch Acosta Produce Ctn B
Flame 19#Pouch Acosta Produce Ctn B
Flame 19#Pouch SO2 J.A.P. Black 5L Styro B
Red Globe 21#PlainSO Chelan Starr 7L Sty
Red Globe 21#PlainSO Chelan Starr 7L Sty
Sugraone 19#Pouch Free Bird Ctn B
Summer Royal 19#Pouch SO2 SF White Od 5L Styro A
Summer Royal 19#Pouch Top Gun Cnt A
```

and having a list of categories like this: Select inid from inventory where type ='Variety' and I get the list as below:

```
    invid     
--------------
 Sugraone
 Autumn Royal
 Flame
 Summer Royal
 Red Globe
```

Now the question is how to loop through the list out this category list using LIKE on a function for counting out on the list of inventory items and get the result as below

```
    invid     |  count   
 Sugraone     | 1
 Autumn Royal | 2
 Flame        | 3
 Summer Royal | 2
 Red Globe    | 2
```

so far I tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jap.category_lookup()
 RETURNS TABLE(variety text, count bigint) AS
 $func$
 DECLARE
   category text;
 BEGIN
   FOR category IN
    SELECT quote_ident(invid)
    FROM   jap.inventories
    WHERE  type LIKE 'Variety'
LOOP
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
  'SELECT count(v.*), category
   FROM jap.lots_name_view v 
   WHERE  name like '% || category || '%';  
END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I get errors

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: || text
LINE 3:        WHERE  name like '% || category || '%'
                                   ^
```

What would be the right approach to use the LIKE clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you use a loop for this query?  Just do something like this:

```
select count(*), i.invid as category
from jap.lost_name_view v join
     jap.inventories i
     on  v.name like '%' || i.invid || '%' 
where exists (select 1
              from jap.inventories i
              where
             )
group by i.invid;
```